# How to invoke Lambda expression using Expression class?

Tags: c#, delegates, expression

I have an expression that contains Func<,> delegate. I'm trying to invoke it and to get the integer value as result

```
class Program
{
    static Expression TestMethod(Expression<Func<int, int>> expression)
    {
        return expression;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var expr = TestMethod(i => i + 1);

        var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>> (expr).Compile().Invoke(1);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

When I Invoke expression, I get next error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateLambdaArgs(Type delegateType, Expression& body, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters, String paramName)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[TDelegate](Expression body, String name, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[TDelegate](Expression body, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[TDelegate](Expression body, ParameterExpression[] parameters)
>      at TestConsoleApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\programming\portfolio\TestConsoleApp\TestConsoleApp\Program.cs:line 22

How can I get the result of the Func<,> delegate invocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're wrapping a lambda in a lambda... this is not what you want. Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Expression<Func<int, int>> expr = i => i + 1;

        var result = expr.Compile().Invoke(1);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

If you want to use the "passthrough" TestMethod, you can do this:

```
class Program
{
    static Expression TestMethod(Expression<Func<int, int>> expression)
    {
        return expression;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var expr = TestMethod(i => i + 1);

        var result = ((Expression<Func<int, int>>)expr).Compile().Invoke(1);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Or if you want to rebuild the lambda from a non-generic expression:

```
class Program
{
    static LambdaExpression TestMethod(Expression<Func<int, int>> expression)
    {
        return expression;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var expr = TestMethod(i => i + 1);

        var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(expr.Body, expr.Parameters).Compile().Invoke(1);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: For same reason, I wanted to use Expression instance to store Expression<Func<int, int>>. I see that your decision will work. Don't you mind if i will ask you to help me to invoke my delegate from - Expression expr: Expression expr = TestMethod(i => i + 1);

Comment: @EvgeniyMiroshnichenko I added some code which hopefully is what you're looking for.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for!